# Selenium: Why isn't a button click carried out?

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to click the "Search" button on a website. Then the next page opens. The click is not carried out (not even with built-in time.sleeps(3)), but an error message is not thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('G:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.immobilienscout24.de")
driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"


element = driver.find_element_by_id("oss-location")
#element.clear()
element.send_keys("10115 Berlin")

btn=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='oss-main-criterion oss-button button-primary one-whole']")))
#btn.click()#trial 1
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn) #trial 2
print("ready")
```

Comment: did you print your `btn` variable n see if it's printing any elements at all ?

Comment: print(btn.text) -> result "Suchen" (i.e. the button is found)

Comment: please add the html code aswell

Comment: ok i ran the code . if you give `time.sleep(3)` after the `element.send_keys()` line , & after clicking `suchen`, the  button text changes to `941 treffer`  -  do you want to click on that new button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest after inserted the value in search box wait for auto search result and then click the auto search result.Then click on the  `treffer` button.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('G:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.immobilienscout24.de")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"oss-location"))).send_keys("10115 Berlin")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][contains(.,'10115 Berlin')])[1]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='oss-main-criterion oss-button button-primary one-whole']//span[contains(.,'Treffer')]"))).click()
```